# How to Both Pass an Argument Into a Function and Get a Return Value in Bash?

Tags: bash, parameters, return, arguments

My code is very simple.

```
variable=$( createTable $table_name )
```

or

```
returnedVariable=$( function $argument )
```

My code breaks on this line. I haven't been able to find anywhere on the internet how to **both** pass an argument and get a return value in Bash.

UPDATE: I get it now. I can't have multiple echo's in my function. Also echo should never be considered a return but a print statement or stdout which you can capture. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: What doesn't work? What does `createTable` look like? Do you have a function named `function`? `function` is a reserved word in Bash.

Comment: The first looks ok unless there are embedded spaces or special chars. Try quotes around the subshell - `variable="$( createTable $table_name )"`

Comment: @PaulHodges `var=$(cmd)` is the same as `var="$(cmd)"`, but `$table_name` should be quoted.

Answer (score 6):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ function createTable() { echo "this is the table: $1"; }    
$ var=$(createTable "$table_name")
$ echo "$var"
this is the table: New Table
```

note that there is nothing returned from the function, that's reserved for the success/error status.  Here will default to zero.  The conceptual "function return value" is through the stdout.  These are not "functions" in mathematical sense.

Comment: Yes! That is it!

 I think it may be that one can't have multiple "echo"s in a function. Is the last echo treated as a return or the first echo the function comes across?

Comment: The exit status of a function is the exit status of the last command executed by the function.

Comment: @Snoopy You seem to be talking about *output*, not a return value. The output of *all* the `echo` commands produces the output of the function.

Comment: That makes sense! To clarify, you are saying that all of the echo commands within the function are being returned?

Comment: Don't use that terminology.  Nothing is returned (except the status).  `echo` is send to stdout which you can capture.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the exit status of the assignment is the exit status of the command substitution.

```
$ var=$(echo "hi"; exit 3)
$ rv=$?
$ echo "$var"
hi
$ echo "$rv"
3
```